# Enable one operator() based on the dimension

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I'd like to create a `form` class that, based on its template arguments, provides one `operator()` with one or more parameters. This is a prototype for curves, for example linear, bilinear, and so on.

So, if the form dimension is `n`, the operator should have `n` integer parameters, so linear forms with `formdim == 1` should have `operator()(i)` while `formdim == 2` I would like `operator()(i, j)`.

I thought `enable_if` could be of any help, but I am not really knee-deep into TMP, and I have a compile error:

```
template<unsigned int formdim>
class form
{
public:
    form()
    {}

    auto operator()(unsigned int j) -> typename std::enable_if<formdim == 1, unsigned int>::type
    {
        std::cout << "LINEAR" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Here I get a compiler error due to the missing type
    auto operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) -> typename std::enable_if<formdim == 2, double>::type
    {
        std::cout << "BILINEAR" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

How can I provide such a class? I don't need the number of parameters being *automatic*, I could manually add new operators as I need them... but obviously it would be very cool indeed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enable_if` must depend directly on a template argument of whatever you are declaring. In your case, you are depending on a template argument for your class, not for the method you are declaring. Add a template argument to your methods and give it the value of your class's template argument. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<unsigned int formdim>
class form
{
public:
    form()
    {}

    // Use T instead of formdim in enable_if
    template<unsigned int T = formdim>
    auto operator()(unsigned int j) -> typename std::enable_if<T == 1, unsigned int>::type
    {
        std::cout << "LINEAR" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Use T instead of formdim in enable_if
    template<unsigned int T = formdim>
    auto operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) -> typename std::enable_if<T == 2, double>::type
    {
        std::cout << "BILINEAR" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{

    form<1> x;
    form<2> y;
    x(42);
    y(42, 43);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you could make use of [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (i.e., static if clause) and do it as:

```
template<unsigned int formdim>
class form {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
      if constexpr (formdim == 1) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 1);
       std::cout << "LINEAR" << std::endl;
       return 0;
      } else if constexpr (formdim == 2) {
       static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 2);
       std::cout << "BILINEAR" << std::endl;
       return 0.0;
      } else {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) < 3);
        return 0;
      }
    }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/asuD79D9AeX05yPJ)